# PHP changing array format

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to change an array format from this

```
{"updated":"2016-01-28 02:00:02","rate":"0.1898"}
```

to this

```
[2016-01-28 02:00 , 0.1898]
```

I'm getting the first array format from a MySQL query and need to convert to the second format to use in a line chart.

```
$newVal = array();
foreach ($dbresult as $key => $value) {
    $newVal[] = json_encode(array_values($value)); 
}

echo implode(",", $newVal);
```

With this new code block i get this format

```
["2016-01-28 02:00" , "0.1898"]
```

But still need to get rid of the double quotes, any ideas?

Comment: In a chart you probably have more than a single key/value. Please post examples of more data.

Comment: HI devpro, no. I'm pulling the data from the database and storing it in to a array, then converting the array to json -echo json_encode ($dbresult);- and using it in a javascript line chart -var dbresult = <?php echo json_encode($dbresult) ?>; ---data.addRows(dbresult);---

Comment: you are correct my array has many key/values, and it will change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$string =  ' {"updated":"2016-01-28 02:00:02","rate":"0.1898"}';
$array = json_decode($string, true);
$str = json_encode(array_values($array));
echo str_replace('"', '', $str);
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `[{"updated":"2016-01-28 02:00:02","rate":"0.1898"},{"updated":"2016-01-28 02:00:02","rate":"0.1898"}]`

Comment: This does not guarantee any particular order, which seems to be required in the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '[{"updated":"2016-01-28 02:00:02","rate":"0.1898"}]';

echo json_encode(array_map(function ($data) {
    return [$data->updated, $data->rate];
}, json_decode($json)));
```

In other words:

1. JSON-decode it
2. loop through it
3. create a new array with `updated` in the first index and `rate` in the second
4. JSON-encode it again

Step 3 is necessary since JSON objects don't guarantee any particular order, so relying on the decoded order of the keys is not reliable; and it also guarantees you get the data you want even if you add more keys to your objects.

Answer (score 0):

> you should try this

```
    $str ='{"updated":"2016-01-28 02:00:02","rate":"0.1898"}';
    $data=json_decode($str);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'json decode it returns ojbects<br>';
    print_r($data);
    echo 'convert object into array<br>';
    $data=(array)$data;
    print_r($data);
    echo 'Your Output<br>';
    echo json_encode(array_values($data));
```

[image: O/P :-]